# Tethering not working on rooted phone (both WiFi and USB), free third-party apps also fail

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

I recently **rooted** my [Huawei GL07S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_STREAM_X_GL07S) and switched to an operator which explicitly allows tethering (I inserted the new SIM card into the GL07S).

When I go to `Settings`>`Wireless&Networks`>`Tethering&Pocket WiFi` I get this screen:

[image: Tethering & Pocket WiFi]

"Pocket WiFi" is a term used by my previous operator to describe tethering, I suspect them of having modified it to work only on their network. I can't use CyanogenMod/similar as they don't support the GL07S, which is a rare phone.

## Default USB Tethering

When I press "USB tethering", the white circle becomes green with a check, and `Pocket WiFi active or Tethering` appears in the notification bar, but the connected Ubuntu does not see any connection:

[image: Ubuntu no Ethernet connection]

## Default WiFi Tethering

Alternatively, when I press "Pocket WiFi", the item becomes grey, the caption becomes `Turning Wi-Fi on…`, and it stays like this forever:

[image: Turning Wi-Fi on]

Meanwhile `adb logcat` keeps outputting things like forever ([longer log](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/1034262133b4f536901c)):

```
E/WifiStateMachine(  341): DefaultState: cannot get Soft AP current connected stations list
D/WifiService(  341): getApLinkedStaList
I/TetherSettings(17288): set PROPERTY_USBTETHERING_ON: false
I/WifiApEnabler(17288): set iswifihotspoton = true
```

To get it back from its grey state, the only solution is to restart the phone.

## [Barnacle Wifi Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.szym.barnacle)

When I press `Start`, I get:

[image: Barnacle WiFi GL07S]

## [Open Garden WiFi Tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=og.android.tether)

When I press `Start Open Garden Tethering` I get this crash:

[image: Open Garden GL07S]

... and `logcat` says:

```
D/TETHER -> TetherApplication( 4591): Reporting stats: {fbon=false, ffox=false, nflt=true, fbok=0, root=true, phon=true, fbau=false, aid=e2a4f1ff707f9812, inst=1433847285, ertm=false, coac=0, sfap=true, c2dm=false, aver=4.1.2, side=1, mno=NTT DOCOMO, blth=true, setu=default, tver=47, rssc=0, bdwn=0, devi=default, asdk=16, imei=869065010878620, fbcr=0, pkg=og.android.tether, dtyp=generic, loc=35.6653574,139.733107, fbco=0, widg=0, fber=0, stat=1, comc=0, bup=0, mfr=HUAWEI, idrv=wext, temp=360, bin=true, uuid=E2A4F1FF-707F-9812-021X-XR2136017743, actl=true, tpow=true, mdl=GL07S}
D/TETHER -> TetherService( 4591): Service started: true, state: 1
D/TETHER -> TetherApplication( 4591): onlyEncryptionOrNothingFailed()
E/AndroidRuntime( 4591):        at og.android.tether.TetherApplication.displayToastMessage(TetherApplication.java:1341)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4591):        at og.android.tether.TetherApplication.readLogfile(TetherApplication.java:1421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4591):        at og.android.tether.TetherApplication.onlyEncryptionOrNothingFailed(TetherApplication.java:1438)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4591):        at og.android.tether.TetherService$1.run(TetherService.java:256)
D/TETHER -> ServiceReceiver( 4591): onReceive:Intent { act=og.android.tether.intent.STATE flg=0x10 cmp=og.android.tether/.TetherServiceReceiver (has extras) } state:1
D/TETHER -> TetherApplication( 4591): Reporting of stats complete
W/ActivityManager(  349): Scheduling restart of crashed service og.android.tether/.TetherService in 5000ms
```

## [ClockworkMod][8]

ClockworkMod is the only tethering app that works reliably (over USB). It is not free, though, so I would like to make it work with the built-in solution or with the open source Barnacle.

## [EasyTether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mstream.e2t)

It has worked the first time I tried it. Since then, no way to use it anymore, it always says `cannot claim USB interface: Device or resource busy`.

## [FoxFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxfi)

When I push `Activate WiFi Hotspot`, it says `WiFi Hotspot Ready`, I can connect to the WiFi network from Ubuntu, but unfortunately all HTTP and HTTPS requests fail:

$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.43.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable

Actually, the phone itself also loses Internet connectivity:

[image: Android ping]

## Question

What is going wrong?
How can I use Internet on my Ubuntu using my phone's LTE data connection? (preferably without having to install a computer-side agent)

Comment: Do you have android sdk for linux installed already (from the looks of things you were using  linux, but since you said you are not keen on anything that installs extra stuff on your PC) I had to put my solution on hold to confirm first?

Comment: How about trying my solution here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/250609/usb-tether-to-router-and-then-connect-to-the-wifi-of-the-router-no-longer-possib/252641#252641

Answer (score 1):

> It always says cannot claim USB interface: Device or resource busy

This is because you have adb running in your system. ADB opens USB interface so no other app can access it. Stop adb either with `killall adb` or using `adb kill-server` (assuming the adb binary is in your `PATH`).

Comment: I restarted my PC, ran `adb kill-server` and enabled USB tethering: The Ethernet connection still does not appear on the PC :-/

Comment: I belive thats because it requires certain drivers to be installed in order to work and most probably isnt supported with Linux

Comment: It is supported in Linux, I have connected to my phone network many many times, not only using WiFi tether but also Bluetooth and USB. However, after rooting I started having issues.