# USB tether to router and then connect to the WiFi of the router no longer possible on recent Android versions?

Tags: wi-fi, usb-tethering, router

I have somewhat of an unusual problem that wasn't a problem a few months ago, I had an Xperia X with Android 8 on it, and I used it to provide Internet (4G) for my devices using a router. It worked like so:

1. Connect to the router's USB
2. Configure router
3. Enable USB Tethering from the phone
4. Internet

This is the usual method, of course. The thing is, I have a NAS attached to the router as well, and I used to enable the WiFi on my phone (with USB Tethering on), and sync/connect with the NAS without losing Internet connection.

I upgraded to a Pixel and then a Samsung running Android 11, 12, and now 13, and there seems to be a change in what WiFi is. It's now related to the "Internet" instead of being a networking means that can be used to get files from a local server offline. Now because of this change, whenever I connect to the WiFi network of the router, I lose Internet (on Samsung) or simply the WiFi wouldn't even connect unless I disable the data (Pixel).

Is there a solution to restore the old behavior or at least workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by connecting a $50 Amazon USB-C Dock with a 1Gbs Ethernet port connected to an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S22+ Ultra, 256GB, latest updates), then turning on ethernet tethering works like a charm. I connect it to a DD-WRT ACM3200 Linksys and share 5G with the network via ethernet and WiFi and get 300Mbps down and 50-60Mbps up, from ethernet and WiFi access from devices connected to the router.

I use it in a warehouse in the boonies and has no problem with 4 NetGear Arlo cameras, Samsung SmartThings with 2 Kwikset 914 ZigBee (door locks now on the remote control and a history log of when locks were unlocked), a laptop (with TeamViewer access for remote control), and 4 WiFi energy monitoring outlets to all things but ceiling lights, running 24/7.

I also use AirDroid to remote control the Android phone in case the ethernet tethering disconnects so I can re-enable it, but after the first few days, it has been stable for weeks.